# Cell Split Excel VBA using Multi-dimensional Array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to split multi-line text box and paste the output on the next sheet in MS Excel using VBA, and I found a fragment of code below and it works:

```
    Dim Str As String, a
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim w()

    Str = xmlRequestTextBox.Value
    a = Chr(10)
    cnt = UBound(Split(Str, a))
    MsgBox (Str)
    MsgBox (a)
    MsgBox (cnt)
    ReDim w(1 To cnt + 1, 1 To 1)

    For i = 0 To cnt
     w(i + 1, 1) = Split(Str, Chr(10))(i)
    Next i

    Sheet2.range("A1").Resize(i, 1) = w
    Sheet2.Cells.Replace Chr(13), " "
```

Now my problem is when I tried to modify it and change it to a single dimensional array, it only outputs the value of the first index of the array. Why does the array have to be multi-dimensional? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-line text you would need to use 2d-array returning by `Split()` function, where the first dimension typically refers to the rows (lines) and second index is referring to the individual words in these lines. Hope this may help.

Comment: Hi Alex thank you for that information, may you explain the for why Split has an (i)?

Answer (score 0):

an example of using split

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Str As String
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim w As Variant

Str = Me.xmlRequestTextBox.Value
w = Split(Str, Chr(10))
cnt = UBound(w)
MsgBox (Str)
MsgBox (Chr(10))
MsgBox (cnt)

' suppose the multi-line textbox value is:
' first line : 1 2 3
' second line: 4 5 6
' third line:  7 8 9
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("split")
    .Range("A1").Resize(cnt + 1) = w(1) ' writes "4 5 6" in A1:A3 (i.e. the 2nd element of w)
    .Range("B1").Resize(cnt + 1) = Split(w(0), " ")(2) ' writes "3" in B1:B3 (i.e. the third element of the 1st element of w)
    .Cells.Replace Chr(13), " "
End With

End Sub
```

where I assumed that there's some UserForm with a multi-line textbox named "xmlRequestTextBox" and a button named "CommandButton1", whose click event starts that piece of code of yours

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the array does **not** have to be multi-dimensional. However, Excel assumes a 1-dimensional array will be *horizontal*, that is, fill the *columns* in a **single row**. So if you're writing to a *vertical* range (*multiple rows* in a **single column**) in a spreadsheet, it will take the value of the first element (column) and write it to each cell in the column. For example, let's assume you have an array like this:

```
MyArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

This code will write the **first element only** of MyArray to the *vertical* range in **column A**:

```
Set MyRange = Range("A1").Resize(5, 1)    ' Cells A1:A5
MyRange.Value = MyArray
```

Result:

```
    A | B | C | D | E
  +---+---+---+---+---+
1 | 1 |   |   |   |   |
2 | 1 |   |   |   |   |
3 | 1 |   |   |   |   |
4 | 1 |   |   |   |   |
5 | 1 |   |   |   |   |
```

If you write the array to a *horizontal* range in a **single row** then it will display the *whole array*:

```
Set MyRange = Range("A1").Resize(1, 5)    ' Cells A1:E1
MyRange.Value = MyArray
```

Result:

```
    A | B | C | D | E
  +---+---+---+---+---+
1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
2 |   |   |   |   |   |
3 |   |   |   |   |   |
4 |   |   |   |   |   |
5 |   |   |   |   |   |
```

However, I'm assuming you actually want to write the array to a *vertical* range in a **single column**. You can accomplish this by using the *Application.WorksheetFunction.**Transpose*** method on the array. This will write each element of the array into rows in column A:

```
Set MyRange = Range("A1").Resize(5, 1)    ' Cells A1:A5
MyRange.Value = Application.Transpose(MyArray)
```

Result:

```
    A | B | C | D | E
  +---+---+---+---+---+
1 | 1 |   |   |   |   |
2 | 2 |   |   |   |   |
3 | 3 |   |   |   |   |
4 | 4 |   |   |   |   |
5 | 5 |   |   |   |   |
```

For more information on this, see Chip Pearson's page on [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)